# <ol> with some <li>s having pseudo-elements and others not

Tags: css, pseudo-element, css-counter

```
1. quick brown fox
<2. jumped over>
<3. the lazy dog>
```

I want to have some `<li>`s in a single `<ol>` styled with `::before` and `::after` pseudo-elements (the < and > in items 2 and 3 above). Right now, I have it built as two lists. I am trying to find a way to do that using just one `<ol>` rather than two, so I can avoid having to use `counter-reset`.

```css
.li_var {
  counter-reset: lt 1;
}
.li_var > li {
  counter-increment: lt;
}
.li_var > li::before {
  content: "<" counter(lt);
}
.li_var > li::after {
  content: ">";
}
```

```html
<ol>
  <li>quick brown fox</li>
</ol>
<ol class="li_var">
  <li>jumped over</li>
  <li>the lazy dog</li>
</ol>
```

**my working solution:**

```
.li_var {
    list-style-type:none;
}
.li_var > li {
    counter-increment: lt;
}
.li_var > li:before {
    content: counter(lt) '. ';
}
.li_var li:nth-child(2), .li_var li:nth-child(3) {
     margin-left:-.6em;
}
.li_var li:nth-child(2):before, .li_var li:nth-child(3):before {
     content: '<' counter(lt) '. ';
}
.li_var li:nth-child(2):after, .li_var li:nth-child(3):after {
     content:'>';
}
```

Comment: Logically, does this content belong to two distinct lists? If so, why put it in one list - would this not negatively impact visitors using assistive technology?

Comment: It really does belong in one list.  I hadn't considered assistive technology.  What would be the issue there?

Comment: The issue is a conflation of two different lists, or the unnecessary division of one logical list. Either way, you could leave the end-user confused. Imagine I send you to the store to pick up: 1. Cheese, 2. Milk, 3. Cereal, and 1. Bread.

Comment: Understood.  Do you feel that the issue is resolved by having one list?

Comment: That depends entirely on the content of the list(s). My only desire here is that you consider the logical structure of what you're building, as much as you consider the visual presentation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the [adjacent sibling combinator, `+`](http://www.w3.org/wiki/CSS/Selectors/combinators/adjacent), in order to select the `li` elements with preceding `li` siblings:

```css
.li_var {
    padding-left: 0;
}
.li_var > li {
    counter-increment: lt;
}
.li_var > li:before {
    content: counter(lt) '. ';
}
.li_var > li + li:before {
    content: '<' counter(lt) '. ';
}
.li_var > li + li:after {
    content: '>';
}
```

```html
<ol class="li_var">
  <li>quick brown fox</li>  
  <li>jumped over</li>
  <li>the lazy dog</li>
</ol>
```

Comment: For my purposes, I ended up using :nth-child instead of the + combinator.

Comment: @Marcelo Probably because I answered first.. not sure though? I just upvoted yours.

Comment: I ran both sets of code and the other rendered more accurately for my situation, because of the padding-left situation - it gave me the idea to do margin-left in my code.  I'm upvoting yours, and I appreciate your answer.

Answer (score 2):

Based on your desired effect, you can use the [`first-child`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/%3Afirst-child), [`last-child`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/%3Alast-child), [`nth-child`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/%3Anth-child), etc CSS selectors to control which elements get styled.

Here is a quick example using `first-child`:

```css
.li_var > li {
  counter-increment: lt;
}
.li_var > li::before {
  content: "<" counter(lt);
}
.li_var > li::after {
  content: ">";
}
.li_var > li:first-child::before {
  content: "";
}
.li_var > li:first-child::after {
  content: "";
}
```

```html
<ol class="li_var">                             
   <li>quick brown fox</li>   
   <li>jumped over</li>
   <li>the lazy dog</li>
</ol>
```

And here is an example using `nth-child`:

```css
.li_var > li {
  counter-increment: lt;
}
.li_var > li:nth-child(n+2)::before {
  content: "<";
}
.li_var > li:nth-child(n+2)::after {
  content: ">";
}
```

```html
    <ol class="li_var">                             
       <li>quick brown fox</li>   
       <li>jumped over</li>
       <li>the lazy dog</li>
    </ol>
```